# Create mixin from @extend class with SASS?

Tags: sass

I have a class that I can extend:

```
%h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

However im getting too many selectors from doing this. I want to instead create a mixin. I want the CSS output to be:

```
.something {
 font-size: 50px;
}

// Some other code 

.something-else {
 font-size: 50px;
}
```

I can do this with the following but it means having to repeat the rules:

```
%h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
@mixin h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

This causes an error:

```
%h1,
@mixin h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

This works but again the selectors get grouped together so it doenst have the benfit of a mixin that I want

```
%h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
@mixin h1 {
  @extend %h1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@mixin h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
%h1 {
  @include h1();
}
```